# Find the first line containing a time stamp after a specific line in a file

Tags: python, string, search

I'm trying to add time stamps to my search results from a file.

My code is:

```
def findIcommingStats():
    #read the result file
    replication_file = open("result.log", "r")

    #create a new temp file for all the prints we will find
    tempFile = open("incomingTemp.txt", "w")

    #loop over the file and move all relevant lines to another temp file
    for line in replication_file:
            if ((line.find('STATISTICS') >= 0) & ( line.find('DeltaMarkerIncomingData') > 0 ) & ( line.find('Counter') == -1  ) &
                     ( line.find('0.00e+00') == -1 ) & ( line.find('0.00') == -1 ) & ( line.find('description') == -1 ) ):
                            tempFile.write(line)
    #cleanup
    replication_file.close()
    tempFile.close()
```

This gives me the strings I'm searching for in my file, that look like:
"STATISTICS: name=gridDeltaMarkerIncomingData kVolSlot=0 GroupCopy(26764 SiteUID(0x3d1d0445) 0) 0 8582 sec window: Rate: 3.53e-06 MB/sec"

The time stamps are ~20-30 lines before that.
How can I get them to be printed in line \ before the strings?

The time stamps looks like "2015/07/08 10:08:00.079 "

File looks like:

```
2015/07/08 10:14:46.971 - #2 - 4080/4064 - AccumulatorManager: ProcessID= RAW STATS:

<statistics>

STATISTICS: name=gridDeltaMarkerIncomingData kVolSlot=0 GroupCopy(26764 SiteUID(0x3d1d0445) 0) 0 924 sec window: Rate: 0.00e+00 MB/sec
STATISTICS: name=gridDeltaMarkerIncomingData kVolSlot=0 GroupCopy(26764 SiteUID(0x3d1d0445) 0) 0 8582 sec window: Rate: 3.53e-06 MB/sec
STATISTICS: name=gridDeltaMarkerIncomingData kVolSlot=0 GroupCopy(26764 SiteUID(0x3d1d0445) 0) 0 63612 sec window: Rate: 4.23e-06 MB/sec

<more statistics>
```

I want to get that time stamp in RAW STATS line., so it will look like:

```
2015/07/08 10:14:46.971 STATISTICS: name=gridDeltaMarkerIncomingData kVolSlot=0 GroupCopy(26764 SiteUID(0x3d1d0445) 0) 0 924 sec window: Rate: 0.00e+00 MB/sec

2015/07/08 10:14:46.971 STATISTICS: name=gridDeltaMarkerIncomingData kVolSlot=0 GroupCopy(26764 SiteUID(0x3d1d0445) 0) 0 8582 sec window: Rate: 3.53e-06 MB/sec
```

Comment: You are using the binary and operator. This is not what you want, use `and` instead. See e.g. `bool(1 and 2)` and `bool(1 & 2)`.

Comment: I changed the '&' to 'and'. Gave the same result. What does it change?  What's the difference between bool(1 and 2) and bool(1 & 2)?

Comment: Of course it gives the same result. It by chance works for your example, but I provided two examples that differ. You are programming (wrong) C here instead of Python. In C, for the same reason, the `&&`-operator exists, which Python's equivalent is the `and`. But this is just a remark on your actual code, not an attempt to solve your problem. That must wait for another answer/comment.

Comment: If you're looking for the time stamps you'll have to find a criterion to find them. Could you provide some more data? Based on what you write I don't see any possibility for us to work with those time stamps...

Comment: @adrianus I though about something like:

Comment: @adrianus I though about something like: find the first line that starts with 201.\/ after the 'line' you just found. Just not sure how to write this in Python.

deets 10x, got you :)

Comment: Can you upload the text file or post it here? As for what you write, you can check with `if line.starts_with('201.\/'): ...`

Comment: @adrianus I edited the first post with the file structure.

Comment: can you show what output you want?

Comment: @Ankit I edited the first post again to show the desired output.

Comment: Did it work with my answer (or another one)? Consider setting an answer as accepted if it solved your question.

Comment: I combined your solution with Ankit's regex to separate the date from the line and put into variable. It worked out great! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should basically do the job:

```
def stat_entry(line):
    return line.startswith('STATISTICS')

def date_entry(line):
    return line.startswith('20')

def findIcommingStats():
    date = ''
    with open("result.log", "r") as replication_file:
        with open("incomingTemp.txt", "w") as tempFile:
            for line in replication_file:
                if date_entry(line):
                    date = ' '.join(line.split(' ')[:2]) # set new date
                elif stat_entry(line):
                    tempFile.write(date  + ' ' + line) # write to tempfile

findIcommingStats()
```

Output:

```
2015/07/08 10:14:46.971 STATISTICS: name=gridDeltaMarkerIncomingData...
2015/07/08 10:14:46.971 STATISTICS: name=gridDeltaMarkerIncomingData...
2015/07/08 10:14:46.971 STATISTICS: name=gridDeltaMarkerIncomingData...
```

As you see I factored out the `stat_entry` and `date_entry` functions; You might want to change those and add some better criteria to check whether a given line is a date or a statistics entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it and other problems like this using regular expressions.

first you need to find the time stamp

```
 regexTimeStamp = re.complie('\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}')
```

then you can use

```
match = regexTimeStamp.match(Str)
```

here I am using Str as one line in the file.
then use `TimeStamp = match.group()` to get your time stamp

now simillarly use regular expression to find

```
regexStat = re.compile('STATISTICS:')

match1 = regexStat.match(str)
match1.start()
```

will give you the beginning index of STATISTICS:
you can append your TimeStamp before that.

[here is a guide on regex](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

[and here is for hit and try](https://regex101.com/)